# Bootstrap - How to keep space between bootstrap columns while resizing (vertical and horizontal)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

I created space between my bootstrap columns using columns insight columns. However, when I start resizing the window, the distance between the columns gets smaller and disappears eventually, both columns start overlapping ech other. How can I keep the space when resizing using bootstrap? Thanks!!!

http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/604/

HTML:

```
<header id="home">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row center-block home_boxes_row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="col-xs-12 home_box_left">
                   <p>teststetsttsgdbdshchdchdchdfvhfvhfvndvhdvvf</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="col-xs-12 home_box_right"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#home {
  height: 1100px;
  background-image: url("https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/85/48/e6/seven-mile-beach-grand.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  .home_boxes_row {
    margin-top: 200px;
    .home_box_left {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: $green;
      padding: 5px;
    }
    .home_box_right {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background-color: $blue;
      padding: 5px;
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Mate, that's not Bootstrap 3 that you are loading in jsfiddle there.

Comment: sorry, updated my post with the right link.

Comment: Updated? What updated? You are still loading Bootstrap 4 there. Try to pay attention to the actual version of Bootstrap you are loading. That matters quite a bit. BS3 and BS4 are completely incompatible with each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boostrap is built with responsiveness in mind. Thereby, setting the width of the two columns to a pixel width, will in most cases break the layout. The width should rather be left to be handled by bootstrap.

The following snippets should provide you what you seek.

Spacing is achieved by creating a div inside of the columns, and then setting margins. I have added separate classes for this (.spacing_right and  .spacing_left).

I have used Bootstrap 4, but it should work with Bootstrap 3 as well.
**Note:** bootstrap 4 has replaced the col-xs-* with col-*.

```css
#home {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 1100px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-s/0e/85/48/e6/seven-mile-beach-grand.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
}

.home_boxes_row {
  margin-top: 200px;
}

.home_box_left {
  background-color: orange;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.home_box_right {
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.spacing_right {
  height: 100%;
  margin-right: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}

.spacing_left {
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 25px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id="home">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row home_boxes_row">
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-6 home_box_left">
            <div class="spacing_right">
              <p>Test test teasdasdst</p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-6 col-6 home_box_right">
            <div class="spacing_left">
              <p>Test test teasdasdst</p>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! One more question: How can I controll the width of the (in this example) colored divs if I cannot set the width? I tried to change col-xs-12 to col-xs-8 etc. - that does not work - if I put a div insight the columns, i works = divs still do not overlap each other on resizing and have the width that I want BUT then the space between the columns becomes too big.How could I control space AND width of the colored divs? Thanks for taking the time!